# Getting all document from temp file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, temporary-files

I am developing iPad app and trying to get all saved pdfs urls and names from temp file. I am able to write but can't figure out how to get them all as Nsobject. You can see my writing code:

```
func  downpdf(getpdfurl: URL,docname:String){
let request = URLRequest(url:  getpdfurl)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session =  URLSession(configuration: config)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response,  error) in
    if error == nil{
        if let pdfData = data {
            let pathURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("\(docname).pdf")
            do {
                try pdfData.write(to: pathURL, options: .atomic)
                
            }catch{
                print("Error while writting")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
            }
        }
    }else{
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
}); task.resume()
}
```

**Edited**

```
  let pathURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent(".pdf")
    print(loadFileFromLocalPath(pathURL.absoluteString)!)
    

                do {
                    let pdfData = try String(contentsOf: pathURL)
                    for i in pdfData {
                        print(i)
                    }
                    
                }catch{
                    print("Error while writting")
```

Comment: _"...how to get them all as Nsobject"_, what does that mean, could you describe the problem a bit better? And post the code you have an issue with as well.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added to related code. I do not know how to get all pdf url and names , and append them to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get all the pdf files in the Documents folder

```
let documentFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

do {
    let pdfUrls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentFolderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.contentTypeKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).filter { $0.pathExtension == "pdf"}

    for url in pdfUrls {
        print(url)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```